# Seperate admin page for each role

Tags: 7, users

I have on my website several roles and each of these roles have different levels of responsibility. How can I create a separate administration page for each role or access level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a number of ways you can accomplish this, here's a few off the top of my head (in no particular order):

- Create a normal page node and use [Node Privacy by Role](http://drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole), a module which allows you fine-grain access control on a per-node basis using roles.
- Use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create an admin page and limit the access using Views's "Access Restrictions."
- Use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) to create an admin panel and limit the access using Panel's "Access Restrictions" (very similar to Views).
- Use [Contexts](http://drupal.org/project/context), create an admin Context and display the content conditionally.

Basically, there is no best or worst way, it all depends on how your current site is set up.  For example if you are already using Panels, it might make sense to go that route, etc.

Personally, I would use a mixture of Contexts and Views!

Comment: It also helps to use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to direct users of each role to their own specific admin starting page (upon login)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) modules for this.